# Python 2.7.5 inputting information into a list using the questions in another list as a prompt

Tags: python, list

i am trying to create a program in Python 2.7.5 that pulls information from a list, gives each item in the list a value, and then puts that value into another list.  ideally, it would look like this:

```
Questions = ["Who are you?"]  
def Test ():  
    Answers = [raw_input (Questions (i))]
```

this might be a simple fix, but for the life of me i can't seem to figure it out.  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
questions = ["Who are you? ", "What's your age? "]
answers = [raw_input(q) for q in questions]
```

This runs like

```
>>> questions = ["Who are you? ", "What's your age? "]
>>> answers = [raw_input(q) for q in questions]
Who are you? Hugh
What's your age? 39
>>> answers
['Hugh', '39']
```

Comment: i tried that, but instead of coming up with the items in the list, it just names the list and asks for input.  i need it to give back the items in the first list as prompts.